# How to use a network for prediction in Deep Learning 4 j?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

As a beginner in *deep learning* I am currently practicing using the project called [deep learning 4 j](http://deeplearning4j.org/).

I am getting really good at the "training" and "evaluating" part of deep learning, but how am I supposed to deploy my finished network in an application? It seems that there are no good example of using a network ( a.k.a prediction) in the [examples for dl4j](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples).

So to be 100% concrete; in a *java context*, what is the leanest way to deploy a network/model created in **dl4j** for use in an application such as a mobile phone app (**Android**)?

Are there any **maven**/**gradle** lines that will get me just the dependencies needed for prediction (as opposed to the whole toolset)?

What is a minimal source code example for using my network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newest release, you can use just deeplearning4j-nn. That's the configuration dsl. You typically need deeplearning4j-core though.

We try to separate as many thing as we can.

Also re: android. Dl4j has a lot of native bits underneath. Please come in to our chat we list on deeplearning4j.org when you try it so we can interactively help you there.

Comment: TIP: Getting up and running with JNI for Android is trivial in Android Studio, also there is official support for OpenCL in Android NDK for several chip vendors so you should be able to have at least some of your native bits run native on Android as well!

Comment: Thanks Will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

DeepLearning4J has a [tutorial](https://deeplearning4j.org/android) about how to deploy to Android.

In addition, I found a [demo](https://github.com/vogon101/MachineLearning) which also uses DeepLearning4J to recognize digits.

I also created [an Android app](https://github.com/flyman3046/MNIST_DL4J) based on DeepLearning4J.